# How to catch some key "being held" in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm making a bash script, I want to make it so when user *hold* key "h", the script displaying help message, and when *released*, it hides the message.

How could I do that? Thankss.

Comment: This is quite sparse a request. Should that work in a console, or in an X terminal environment? Should this work from within a menu? Direct interaction with the keyboard is difficult from within the shell. `xev` might be something to  evaluate;

Comment: @RudiC console, I ended up not using it, back to traditonal way, press once to toggle

Comment: @user312781, as it stands, this question has no value for future readers. You might want to delete it.

Comment: @glennjackman of course. Sorry, I'm on mobile, don't know how to delete it. Make sure I ll delete it when on browser

Comment: Don't worry, no apology required. You seem to have taken your own solution in a different direction. I'm just looking to prune out some no-so-useful questions here.

Comment: glenn Is it customer to guess what is needed or just BS ?